# Drupal 7 how to add content in custom theme

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am developing my custom theme in drupal 7.

I have `.info` , `page.tpl.php` and `style.css file`.

I want to add content *(from admin panel article and other contents)* in my theme.

How will I do this ? I have added `print render($page['content']);` in `page.tpl.php` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the regions in .info file,

```
name = themename
description = Your theme description.
version = 7.x
core = 7.x
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css 

scripts[] = js/yourscript.js 


regions[left] = Left sidebar
regions[right] = Right sidebar
regions[content] = Content
regions[header] = Header
regions[footer] = Footer
```

then clear the cache tho affect the changes.

You can use the same `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` for displaying the content in page.tpl.php

After that **go to admin-> structure->blocks**

Assign "main page content" to the "content" block

More detailed [documentation here.](https://www.drupal.org/node/171194)

Please follow the folder and file naming structure.